# Calculate multiple distances using Pythagoras Theorem

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I've spent many hours trying to resolve this problem. I have a dataset with 6 points (Latitude,Longitude) called `data` in this way:

```
Latitude Longitude
-36.525    -72.951
-36.523    -72.943
-36.522    -72.937
-36.531    -72.954
-36.530    -72.945
-36.529    -72.937
```

The problem asks to calculate the distance between all the points calling a function with the Pythagoras' theorem (without external packages). In fact, I already did it for 1 and 6 but I can't make it work in a loop for all of them. 
My attempt was:

```
#Function
distance<-function (lat2,lat1,lon2,lon1){   
  c <- sqrt((lat2-lat1)^2+(lon2-lon1)^2)
  #Converting to km.
  c <- c*60*1.852
}

#Point 1 and 6
test <- distance(data[6,1],data[1,1],data[6,2],data[1,2])
test
```

But I'm totally obfuscated trying to include it in a loop.

```
for(x in 1:nrow(data)){
  for(y in 1:ncol(data)){
    row <- distance(data[x,y])
  }
}
print(row)
```

Comment: @Pascal Yes, sorry! Mistake typing here

Comment: You can use the `dist()` function if you want to calculate Euclidean distances.

Comment: as @RHertel says, you would just do `dist(data2*60*1.852)`

Comment: if you want to do it similarly yourself, you can use `outer` to create a similar matrix to that returned by `dist`.  Write a function for euclidean distance, vectorized for the inputs to `outer`, `euc <- Vectorize(function(a, b, dat) sqrt(sum((dat[a,]-dat[b,])^2)), c("a","b"))`.  Then, use the row indices as the inputs, `outer(1:nrow(data2), 1:nrow(data2), euc, dat=data2*60*1.852)`

Comment: @bunk Omg, this helped me as hell! It resolved completely my problem. But now I'd love to know how it does. I mean... I'm a newbie in this language and it's the fist time I see these commands. Could you please explain me a bit what Vectorize and Outer does? I understand Vectorize by its syntaxis with R Help, but i'm not fully convinced. Thanks u a lot!!!

Comment: @atlantean haha glad it was useful!  Since you're new to R, it's not surprising you haven't used those functions, but they are very useful.  In R, vectorization basically just means you can pass a vector of arguments to a function and the function will be applied to each one of those arguments in turn (hopefully this will happen in C code).  An alternative way to achieve the same results would be to loop through the arguments and apply the function in the loop.

Comment: The function `outer` requires a vectorized functions (for its first two inputs).  `Vectorize` is simply a function that takes another function as input, and returns a new, hopefully vectorized, version of the function (essentially it just applies the original function in a loop over the function arguments).

Comment: @bunk I'm very grateful to you! My problem is already solved but I wanted to go further and know how it works. I really appreciate it

Comment: Using `dist` or `outer` is the best alternative, nevertheless you should be able to do it easily in a loop, so let me help you with that. The only problem you have is that you assign the computed value in the same variable `row`. During the loop, this single variable takes all the distance values in succession. At the end, `row` contains the last value computed (for `i=nrow(data)` and `j=nrow(data)`). So what you want is to store the successive values in a matrix, and not overwrite the same variable over and over!

Comment: So, to make your loop work: first create an empty matrix (containing NA for example): `mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(data), ncol=ncol(data))`. Then, execute the loop with the instruction `mat[x,y] <- distance(data[x,y])`. It will work! It will be slow as hell and you should really use a vectorized option, but being able to write a loop that works is a basic skill to have :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate a little bit on the comment I made before: the `dist()` function can be used to calculate Eucledian distances between a set of data points. It is fully vectorized, which means that a loop through the coordinates of the points is unnecessary (this is done "under the hood" of the function).

In your example the Euclidean distances could be calculated in the following way:

```
data1 <- read.table(text = "Latitude Longitude
                            -36.525    -72.951
                            -36.523    -72.943
                            -36.522    -72.937
                            -36.531    -72.954
                            -36.530    -72.945
                            -36.529    -72.937", header=TRUE)
dist(data1)*60*1.852 #multipliers to convert into km according to OP
#          1         2         3         4         5
#2 0.9163190                                        
#3 1.5909963 0.6759166                              
#4 0.7454156 1.5113954 2.1374359                    
#5 0.8678749 0.8089658 1.2571793 1.0062344          
#6 1.6179316 0.9428845 0.7778400 1.9020680 0.8958781
```

The output is a (strictly) lower triangular matrix which contains the distances between each pair of the points in the dataset; in this case points 1 to 6.

Comment: It worked! I didn't knew the function "dist". Thank you!